# Polimorfismo y Herencia en Java

Tags: java, poo, herencia, polimorfismo

Me encargaron un trabajo en el cual debo hacer uso del polimorfismo y herencia de POO, el problema es que de 4 "valores" que quiero mostrar solo me muestra 2, me gustaría saber si alguien podría darme una alternativa para esto, no es algo que considere dificil pero sin embargo no me sale jajaja.

El programa es 1 clase main, 1 clase padre con 2 subclases. En el main solo instancio objetos y muestro. En la clase Padre llamada "Persona" escribo los atributos de una persona con un constructor que tiene 3 parametros (nombre,apellidos y edad) y tengo un metodo que me retorna nombre y apellidos. Después tengo la clase Maestro que hereda nombre,apellidos y edad pero también agrega "claveEmpleado", es lo único en esta clase. Por ultimo tengo la clase alumno que es similar a la de maestro pero en lugar de agregar la clave meti la "matricula". A lo que quiero llegar es, quiero que mi programa me muestre algo así.

**output**:

Juan Perez 30 JPMN
Gerardo Martinez 18 123123

pero al correr el programa solo me muestra algo así

**output**:

JuanPerez
GerardoMartinez

*agregó los códigos*:

**Main**

package lab1;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import lab1.core.*;

```
public class Lab1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Persona> personas = new ArrayList();

        Persona maestro = new Maestro("Juan", "Perez", 30, "JPMN");
        Persona alumno = new Alumno("Gerardo", "Martinez", 18, 123123);

        personas.add(maestro);
        personas.add(alumno);

        for(Persona persona:personas){
            System.out.println(persona.obtenerInformacion());
        }   
    }   
}
```

**Persona**

```
public class Persona {

    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    private int edad;

    public Persona(String nombre, String apellidos,int edad){
        setNombre(nombre);
        setApellidos(apellidos);
        setEdad(edad);
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre=nombre;
    }

    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos){
        this.apellidos=apellidos;
    }

    public String getApellidos(){
        return apellidos;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad){
        this.edad=edad;
    }

    public int getEdad(){
        return edad;
    }

    public String obtenerInformacion(){
        String bot= nombre + apellidos;
        return bot;
    }   
}
```

**Maestro**

```
public class Maestro extends Persona{

    private String claveEmpleado;

    public Maestro(String nombre,String apellidos,int edad,String claveEmpleado){
        super(nombre,apellidos,edad);
        this.claveEmpleado=claveEmpleado;
    }

    public void setClaveEmpleado(String claveEmpleado){
        this.claveEmpleado=claveEmpleado;
    }

    public String getClaveEmpleado(){
        return claveEmpleado;
    }
}
```

**Alumno**

```
public class Alumno extends Persona{

    private int matricula;

    public Alumno(String nombre,String apellidos, int edad, int matricula){
        super(nombre,apellidos,edad);
        this.matricula=matricula;

    }


    public void setMatricula(int matricula){
        this.matricula=matricula;
    }

     public int getMatricula(){
        return matricula;
    }
}
```

Todo compila bien, solo tengo esos errores de que no me muestra lo que necesito, de antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Debes sobreescribir el metodo `obtenerInformacion()` en las clases `Maestro` y `Alumno`.

En la clase Maestro:

```
@Override    
public String obtenerInformacion() {
   return this.getNombre() + " " + this.getApellidos() + " " + this.getEdad() + " " + this.getClaveEmpleado();
}
```

Y en la clase alumno:

```
@Override
public String obtenerInformacion() {
   return this.getNombre() + " " + this.getApellidos() + " " + this.getEdad() + " " + this.getMatricula();
}
```

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!!